# perform MITM attack in HTTPS traffic

Tags: http, https, mitmproxy, node-mitm

As we know, we can successfully capture login credentials over unencrypted HTTP traffic. Although HTTPS enforces end-to-end encryption, it is still possible to perform it over HTTPS. But i'm a little confused about the detailed steps. Can someone tell me how to perform MITM attack and sniff HTTPS traffic under certain condition?
I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

An MitM attack on HTTPS connections for example using mitmproxy can only be successful if you control the client application and can make it trust the certificates issued by the mitmproxy integrated CA by [installing the mitmproxy root CA certificate](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/).

On platforms that don't support installing an additional trusted certificate (such as recent Android versions) or where the application itself performs additional checks such as certificate pinning, an MitM attack can be detected by the application and thus no data is transmitted that could be captured by mitmproxy.